# file is getting saved in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.. instead of download folder react-native-image-to-pdf

Tags: android, react-native, download

The pdf file is getting saved in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com. and it's not accessible on the real device I want it to get moved to the download folder

```
import RNImageToPdf from 'react-native-image-to-pdf';

....

    try {
      const options = {
        imagePaths:[],
        name: 'abc.pdf',
        maxSize: {
          // optional maximum image dimension - larger images will be resized
          width: 900,
          height: Math.round((height / width) * 900),
        },
        quality: 0.7, // optional compression paramter
      };
      const pdf = await RNImageToPdf.createPDFbyImages(options); // this is creating pdf and saving the file into storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using expo you can use following [snippet](https://www.farhansayshi.com/post/how-to-save-files-to-a-device-folder-using-expo-and-react-native/):

```js
mport * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

const perm = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.MEDIA_LIBRARY);
if (perm.status != 'granted') {
  return;
}

try {
  const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(downloadedFile.uri);
  const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Download');
  if (album == null) {
    await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Download', asset, false);
  } else {
    await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
  }
} catch (e) {
  handleError(e);
}
```